# Remove the solenoid and the arrows on the magnetic field lines in pst-magneticfield (PStricks)

Tags: pstricks

I'm using pst-magneticfield to draw the magnetic fieldlines of a solenoid.
Something like this:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}

\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.65,-3)(2.65,3)
    \psmagneticfield[linecolor=brown,R=0.5,N=16, L=2, nS=0, nL=8](-2.65,-3)(2.65,3)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to remove the solenoid and the arrows from this drawing, so I'm only left with the field lines (it's a figure for an exam).

I'm not familiar with PStricks (I use tikz), so I really don't know where to start. I read the manual for the package, didn't get me further.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.65,-3)(2.65,3)
    \pstVerb{tx@MFieldDict begin /fleche {} def end }% redefine arrow
    \psmagneticfield[drawSelf=false, 
    linecolor=brown,R=0.5,N=16, L=2, nS=0, nL=8](-2.65,-3)(2.65,3)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]